# Where to find proper info on the cardano graphql

Tags: cardano-graphql

I am new to Cardano and have setup the [GraphQL node](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-graphql)

All is running, but my problem is I can not find proper info on how to actually get the data.
What I would like to query is asset data and smart contract data.

Lets say there is an Cardano DEX, they work with some smart contract and liquidity pool, i would like to get data on what pools and calculate a price from that.

Btw, I try to build a simple Cardano DEX tool with MERN stack.

Any help, any pointing to the right direction is welcome.

-- UPDATE --

So, lets say I need to calculate a pair price which is done from an liquidity pool of a DEX. How to get that data?
Or I want to get sell/buy orders from a DEX.

I know how this works for eth and bsc, all those have awesome documentation, but Cardano is not really made well for new coming dev's to the Cardano blockchain.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you have explored their wiki yet, it has guide how to interact with their api:

[Interacting with the API](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-graphql/wiki/Interacting-With-The-API)

You can also check their API Documentation:

[API Documentation](https://input-output-hk.github.io/cardano-graphql/)

They've got a bunch of samples too:

[Example Queries](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-graphql/tree/master/packages/api-cardano-db-hasura/src/example_queries)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I know all those pages, but non give me the info I need to get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

how do you like this?
i really liked the source of info here:
https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-graphql

Comment: That's the node I have running, but the documentation is so bad for beginners.